# (PHP) MySQL to Excel export generates a file with different cells format

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

Although both DATA 1 & DATA 2 are varchar on my MySQL Database, when I export my table that contains DATA 1 & DATA 2 using PHP (see code below) I get an Excel file where DATA 2 cells are in the General format (which is ok) and DATA 1 cells in Number format (which is not ok, I want them to be general too in order to avoid decimal separator).

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

$sep = "\t";

$sql="SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName WHERE `userID`=$id";  
$resultt = $con->query($sql);
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($resultt)) { //fetch table field 
name
    echo $property->name."\t";
}

fputcsv("\n");    

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultt))  //fetch_table_data
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j< mysqli_num_fields($resultt);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "'$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);

    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", 
    $schema_insert);

    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    fputcsv(trim($schema_insert));
    fputcsv "\n";
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

(Again: DATA 1 is not correct, DATA 2 is correct)

Comment: Try putting a `'` at the start of each field? That tells Excel that the cell is text, even if it looks like a number.

Comment: The fact is that 5.222.688.997.299.520 would become 5222688997299520, while the data on database is 5.222688997299520

Comment: Why would Excel discard the decimal in such a case? It should interpret `'5.222688997299520` as a string with the value `5.222688997299520`.

Comment: Actually I have 5.222.688.997.299.520 that I want it to become 5.222688997299520, if I type ' before 5.222.688.997.299.520 I get 5222688997299520. The point is that I don't want the user that downloads my file to have to do some edits to the file in order to see the correct values. I want my php script to generate an Excel file with the same exact data (same format too) found on the MySQL database.

Comment: I just typed `'5.222.688.997.299.520` into Excel, and the result was `5.222.688.997.299.520`. I admit I'm confused here. You say the database has `5.222.688.997.299.520`, and you want the exact same data in Excel, but you also say that you want it to become `5.222688997299520`. That's *not* the exact same data.

Comment: Here I am, sorry for the delay in answer, on my database I've got 5.222688997299520, on Excel it becomes 5.222.688.997.299.520

Comment: You tried using `$schema_insert .= "'$row[$j]".$sep;` (note single quote added at the beginning of the string) and it didn't work?

Comment: By the way, `"$row[$j]".$sep` is identical to `$row[$j].$sep` and `"$row[$j]$sep"`. If all you're putting inside the double quotes is a single variable, there's no point in using the double quotes.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I'll try in few hours, I'll let you know ASAP.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Again, thanks for your support and sorry for my delay in replying...`"'$row[$j]".$sep;` works fine, except that now each cells begins with '. Is there a way to "hide" that '? `5.222.688.997.299.520` is now shown as`'5.222688997299520` on Excel, and I want it to be shown as `5.222688997299520`

Comment: Weird. I wonder if it's something to do with `print`ing the output. Have you ever looked at `fputcsv`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Not yet, let me try within the day. Will my file be still compatible with Excel's cells formattin using fputcsv()? I mean, will the Excel fill still have a cell for each field instead of a single cell filled with every single value found on the Database?

Comment: Yes, `fputcsv` takes an array and formats it as CSV output, which Excel can read just fine. As an added bonus, it does things like escapes commas in the middle of fields. It does use commas instead of tabs for field separators, though, as per "CSV".

Comment: @GregSchmidt Using fputcsv() I get empty values (only fields name are shown in Excel).

Comment: Maybe edit your question to include your new code?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Do I have to post the new code as an answer?

Comment: No, you edit your question. Posting answers is for answers, not additional information.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Ok I've edited my question with the new and current code.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `fputcsv`? That's not at all how it works.

Comment: I've actually solved by replacing through a SQL REPLACE query each '.' with a ','. If we take in account the nature of the data this even makes more sense. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: @GregSchmidt UPDATE: I've just realized I cannot replace '.' with ',' on my database: it messes some charts that are on my website, fortunately I had made a backup of the DB itself. Would it be possible to adapt fputcsv() to my code?

Comment: Of course, that's why I suggested it. :-) Just read the docs on how the function works. It takes two arguments: a file descriptor which you have to open first, and an array of the values to write out. Lots of examples out there of how to use it.

Comment: @GregSchmidt :) Started to read its documentation. I suppose the array of the values to write out is `$schema_insert`, since I also have to write "\n" **before** and **after** write `$schema_insert`, I'm pretty sure I need to use fputscsv() three times, correct?

Comment: You don't need to write any field separators or line feeds, `fputcsv` takes care of all of that.